# How to correctly execute sql in scripts with private classes

Tags: php, mysqli

Debugging a script that processes form data: multiple text fields, two file uploads (one an image and the other a document). The script is working with my js file to allow the image to be cropped before upload.

I've set up two sql statements in the script below, the first one inserts the text field data into the database, then retrieves the unique and auto-incremented row number ($id) it was inserted to. The second sql statement should insert the url of the image and document to sql, into the same row that the first sql statement submitted data to.

The first sql statement is working, and the files are saving to the server in this script.

The second sql statement is not working, and I think it's because the value for $id is not passing from outside of the class CropAvatar.

Any suggestions how to get the second sql statement here to execute?

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$titlee = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$address = $_POST['address'];
$addresse = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];
$sale_pricee = mysql_real_escape_string($sale_price);
require('../dbcon.php');
$sql="INSERT INTO listings (title, address, sale_price, date_added) VALUES ('$titlee', '$addresse', '$sale_pricee', now())";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
    class CropAvatar {
        private $src;
        private $data;
        private $file;
        private $dst;
        private $type;
        private $extension;
        private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
        private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
        private $msg;
function __construct($src, $data, $file, $id) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setId($id);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
}
        private $id;
        public function setId($id) {
                 $this->id = $id;
}
        private function setSrc($src) {
            if (!empty($src)) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($src);

                if ($type) {
                    $this -> src = $src;
                    $this -> type = $type;
                    $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $this -> setDst();
                }
            }
        }
        private function setData($data) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
            }
        }
        private function setFile($file) {
            $errorCode = $file['error'];

            if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);

                if ($type) {
                    $dir = $this -> srcDir;

                    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                        mkdir($dir, 0777);
                    }
                    $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                    $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                    if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

                        if (file_exists($src)) {
                            unlink($src);
                        }
                        $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
                        $listing_img="http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
                        $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
                        $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                        $extensionf = end($tempf);
                        if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
                        && ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
                        && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
{
    $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

    if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }   
        else 
        {
            if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
            {
             echo $_FILES["flyer"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
                else 
                {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                 }
        }
      $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
      require('../dbcon.php');
$sql="update listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$ID";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
}
                        if ($result) {
                            $this -> src = $src;
                            $this -> type = $type;
                            $this -> extension = $extension;
                            $this -> setDst();
                        } 
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        private function setDst() {
            $dir = $this -> dstDir;

            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
            }

            $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
        }
        private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
            if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                        break;
                }
                if (!$src_img) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                    return;
                }
                $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
                $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
                if ($result) {
                    switch ($this -> type) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (!$result) {
                        $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
                }
                imagedestroy($src_img);
                imagedestroy($dst_img);
            }
        }
        private function codeToMessage($code) {
            switch ($code) {
                default:
                    $message = 'Unknown upload error';
            }
            return $message;
        }
        public function getResult() {
            return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
        }
        public function getMsg() {
            return $this -> msg;
        }
    }
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $id);
    $response = array(
        'state'  => 200,
        'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
        'result' => $crop -> getResult()
    );

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: This code is fairly unreadable. Fix your indenting and move the class to a separate block and it might be easier to parse out what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing DB libraries:

```
$sale_pricee = mysql_real_escape_string($sale_price);
                    ^----
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     ^---
```

The `mysql` (no "i") and `mysqli` (with "i") libraries are NOT interchangeable and you cannot mix/match like that. Since you never bother checking if your queries actually succeeded, you simply ASSUMED nothing could ever go wrong. Bad bad bad assumption. **ALWAYS** assume things will fail, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Assuming you really mean to use the "no-i" version, then always have at least something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And note that mysql is obsolete. You shouldn't be using it anymore, and should be using mysqli or PDO instead.

And you are STILL vulnerable to sql injection attacks, by directly using the `['name']` parameter of $_FILES in your update query.